# Add buld and commit hash to manifest

Tags: java, git, maven, jenkins

I am trying to add jenkins build number, git commit hash, etc... to the MANIFEST.MF  file.  I am following this tutorial:  http://akeffalas.github.io/blog/2014/04/jenkins-build-info-maven-artifacts.html

Here is my build section of my POM:

```
    <build>
    <finalName>common</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Build-Time>${maven.build.timestamp}</Build-Time>  
                        </manifestEntries>
                        <manifestSections>
                            <manifestSection>
                                <name>${build.manifest.section}</name>
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Implementation-Title>com.mycompany.stuff</Implementation-Title>
                                    <Implementation-Version>${project.version}</Implementation-Version>
                                    <Implementation-Build-Number>${build.number}</Implementation-Build-Number>
                                    <Implementation-SCM-Revision>${build.revision}</Implementation-SCM-Revision>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </manifestSection>
                        </manifestSections>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

But when I build it, all I get is this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: jenkins
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_74
```

My build args are:

```
clean install -Dbuild.number=${BUILD_NUMBER} -Dbuild.revision=${GIT_COMMIT}
```

but in the logs,  I do NOT see the assembly plugin being called,  I see clean, compile, resources, jar, and install.  but no assembly.

Is there anything special I need to do to get this plugin to run?  OR am I doing it completely wrong, and I need something else completely?

Comment: It's not `maven-assembly-plugin` but `maven-jar-plugin` that you should use. The tutorial has a mistake.

Comment: That's the answer !  thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help :). I think you can delete this, it is really a typographical error.

Comment: I added a comment on the original tutorial.  I will delete this.

Comment: in your <manifest> tag, you may want to add `                                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
`

Answer (score 5):

For Git, you can have this done automatically.
To get this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: ondra
Build-Time: 2018-10-24T15:04:25Z
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.5.0
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_181
Main-Class: ch.zizka.myapp.MyMainClass

Name: Versions
Implementation-SCM-Revision: 85e0e665
Implementation-Version: 18.22.1-SNAPSHOT
Implementation-SCM-Branch: feature/gitCommitToManifest
```

Use this in `pom.xml`:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals><goal>create</goal></goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <getRevisionOnlyOnce>true</getRevisionOnlyOnce>
                <shortRevisionLength>8</shortRevisionLength>
                <attach>true</attach>
                <addOutputDirectoryToResources>true</addOutputDirectoryToResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Build-Time>${maven.build.timestamp}</Build-Time>
                    </manifestEntries>
                    <manifestSections>
                        <manifestSection>
                            <name>Versions</name>
                            <manifestEntries>
                                <Implementation-Version>${project.version}</Implementation-Version>
                                <Implementation-SCM-Revision>${buildNumber}</Implementation-SCM-Revision>
                                <Implementation-SCM-Branch>${scmBranch}</Implementation-SCM-Branch>
                            </manifestEntries>
                        </manifestSection>
                    </manifestSections>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add git comment information to your package, you can include the following configuration in your `pom.xml` file. The file path in the JAR package will be `BOOT-INF/classes/git.properties`.

```
  <plugin>
        <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.9.10</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>get-the-git-infos</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>revision</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <dotGitDirectory>${project.basedir}/.git</dotGitDirectory>
            <prefix>git</prefix>
            <verbose>false</verbose>
            <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
 
<generateGitPropertiesFilename>${project.build.outputDirectory}/git.properties</generateGitPropertiesFilename>
            <format>json</format>
            <gitDescribe>
                <skip>false</skip>
                <always>false</always>
                <dirty>-dirty</dirty>
            </gitDescribe>
        </configuration>
    </plugin
```

> 