# maven jar/war plugin to add git hash commit id

Tags: git, maven, buildnumber-maven-plugin

I wanted to add the Git commit id in the manifest.mf file for jar.

I have done the below configuration in pom xml plugin configuration,

I am able to get the git revision when  i issue the maven goal
`clean buildnumber:create install`

Is it possible to get the git revision without issuing `buildnumber:create` and through plugin configuration?

pom.xml

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.jarplugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>    
                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>false</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>create</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <doCheck>true</doCheck>
        <doUpdate>true</doUpdate>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: What happens if you execute `mvn clean install`?

Comment: the buildnumber is not availale in manifest.mf

Comment: Try turning on debug logging (with `-X`). Perhaps that will show where the problem happens. In particular, check that the plugins are running in the correct order.

Comment: Hi iam not seeing the buildnumber-maven-plugin executed during clean install.

Comment: Is that plugin in the `<plugins>` section, or `<pluginManagement>`?

Comment: Hi i found the issue the plugins are defined in pluginManagement in parent pom,but was not  included in plugins section in project pom.After including the build number is getting amended now.

Comment: I added it as an answer, so you may accept. Thanks.

Comment: I answered a reference problem in this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77756948/7843104). It might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the plugin is defined in the `<plugins>` section, not just `<pluginManagement>`.